# scala create and use local library

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to create a local library which contains a class

myproject.scala:

```
object test {
    def info(message: String): Unit = println(s"INFO: $message")
}
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "MyProject"
version := "0.1"
organization := "MyCorp"
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"
sbtVersion := "0.13"
```

I ran sbt clean compile publishLocal and I see the jar in my local ivy2 directory.  What I'm unsure about is how to now use that library in another project.

do I added `libraryDependencies += "MyCorp"%"myproject_2.11"%"0.1"`
to the second project's sbt, and I see it in the classPath when I print it out in the repl. The problem is when I try 
import MyCorp.myproject

I get an error not found. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but it's driving me nuts.

Comment: So you've published it locally and it resolves, but the dependent code doesn't compile? Are you importing the right thing? With the code you pasted, you should be doing `import test._`, is there a `package` declaration in `myproject.scala`?

Comment: there isn't a package declaration, is that required. with import test._ I get the same error.

Comment: ok so I tried with putting everything in the package mytest {}   how do I call the import, I tried mytest._ and mytest.test     both have the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I ran sbt clean compile and I see the jar in my local ivy2 directory.

That's weird. `sbt clean compile` does not publish the artifact in the local repository. (Have you copied it manually there?) That should have been done with `publishLocal` command and the artifact should become available at `{path_to_.ivy2}/local/MyCorp/MyProject/0.1/jars/MyProject.jar`.

Now in your second project, it can be added as

```
libraryDependencies += "MyCorp" % "MyProject" % "0.1"
// or in libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...)
```

Please notice that the `_2.11` suffix that you have used in the name depends on how the first project was built, whether its build was differentiated by Scala versions. If it was, the suffix would be usually present in the artifact .jar file name. And it is preferable to avoid including the suffix in the library dependency declaration, but rather use `%%` for built-in support.

After checking it, also try to restart the SBT CLI, because unfortunately sometimes changes in `build.sbt` are not taken into account on-the-fly.

*Update*

> I assume its mycorp.myproject.test , but I tried every possible combination. @Brian

Following the comments, I think that there still should be something misconfigured in the project and/or missing in the description.

Assuming there is a file `{path/to/project}/src/main/scala/mycorp/myproject/Test.scala`, with the following contents:

```
package mycorp.myproject

object Test {
  def info(message: String): Unit = println(s"INFO: $message")
}
```

When the artifact is published, the .jar file should contain the folders `mycorp/myproject` with `Test.class` and `Test$.class` files.

After adding the .jar to the dependencies of the second project, importing `Test` into another class should look like:

```
package mycorp.myproject2

import mycorp.myproject.Test

object AnotherTest extends App {

  Test.info("hello")

}
```

I hope this helps.

*End-of-update*

Comment: I excluded the publishLocal, I ran it after compile. The question is really about what to use for the import statement?

Comment: Which is the fully qualified name of the class that you are trying to import?

Comment: I assume its mycorp.myproject.test  , but I tried every possible combination.